# Crear una clase contenedora para excepciones en Java

Tags: java, excepciones

Estoy aprendiendo o más bien recordando Java. Hace años que no lo toco. A ver he querido hacer una clase que contenga varias excepciones en este caso para validar números, el ejemplo es mundano vamos.No se si es correcto hacerlo así o conoceis otra forma más práctica, me gustaría saber. La idea es tener varias clases para cada tipo de excepciónes personales. Pongo la clase que tiene anidadas clases estaticas para cada excepción, en este caso solo hay dos pero con el tiempo ir añadiendo claro:

```
public class MisExcepcionesNumericas {

static class numeroCero extends Exception{

    public numeroCero(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}

static class numeroDouble extends Exception{

    public numeroDouble(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Luego un ejemplo de como se lanzarían:

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void introducirMayorCero() throws MisExcepcionesNumericas.numeroCero{

    int num;
    
    try {
            
        System.out.println("Introduce el número 0");
        num = sc.nextInt(); 
        if(num < 0)
        throw new MisExcepcionesNumericas.numeroCero("El número introducido es menor a 0");
    } catch (MisExcepcionesNumericas.numeroCero e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Las clases son estaticas para no tener que estar instanciando objetos, pero eso ya va al gusto. Los que llevais mucho tiempo programando como os haceis librerias de excepciones propias.

Comment: me gusta este video que aunque no profundiza si muestra las diferentes formas de manejar excepciones, espero le sea de utilidad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xd-FTaDaSlk

Comment: Gracias @isaac a ver si me dejan y lo veo este sábado. Ya te comento